# Electron did-finish-load also firing on load fail

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to check if the did-finish-load event is caused by a actuall successful load or because there is no internet connection, my current code

```
window.webContents.on('did-fail-load', function(event, code, desc, url, isMainFrame) {
  window.hide();
  loading.show();
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.loadURL(url);
  }, 10000);
});

window.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  loading.hide();
  window.show();
});
```

doesn't work, the `did-finish-load` event also gets triggered when the loading process failed because of no internet connection

Comment: Does `did-finish-load` trigger before, after or simultaneously to `did-fail-load`?

Comment: Is there an initial `loadURL` call that can just be awaited instead of hooking into those events?

Comment: @Jakob did you solve this issue? I happen to have the same problem. What is happening?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you, I ended up dumping electron and that project altogether. Good luck to you!